# Programmatically run knex seed:run

Tags: node.js, knex.js

To seed a database, knex says to run the following script:

```
$ knex seed:run
```

I was looking for a way to do this programmatically (ie in my javascript code). I have the following that compiles without any problems but it only returns a promise and doesn't actually do the seeding:

```
const knexInstance = require('knex')(config);
knexInstance.seed.run()
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: share your knexfile.js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knex is using bluebird under the hood, so to run seed, you need to wait for promise to be finished.

Waiting for promise can be done by standard JavaScript `await`.

```
await knexInstance.seed.run();
```

Knex seed source code: [GitHub](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/blob/master/src/seed/index.js)

Answer (score 4):

You need to wait for that promise to resolve. For example

```
await knexInstance.seed.run();
```